# Is there any ways to retrieve datatable in row field in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve data table in row field has fetch from database. Simply, one to many relationship in result set from stored procedure.

**Table 'car'**

```
Id  Car
1   BMW
2   Mercedes
3   Audi
```

Available in many color

**Table 'CarColor'**

```
Id CarId    Color
1   1     Metalic White
2   1     Acrylic White
3   2     Glossy Red
4   2     Glossy White
5   3     Frosty Black
6   3     Frosty White
```

Consequently, I want result set from stored procedure like

```
Id  Car       CarColor
1   BMW      'CarColor Datatable' (i.e. Datatable of CarColor table relevant row)
2   Mercedes 'CarColor Datatable' (i.e.  Datatable of CarColor table relevant row)
3   Audi     'CarColor Datatable' (i.e.  Datatable of CarColor table relevant row)
```

Comment: Thats not how SQL works in general, unless your RDBMS can transform a subquery or something to JSON on-the-fly. Normal solution is to do a join, which will for each "car" return as many rows as there are the associated "colors" (with the "car" columns duplicated in each row) and then group these the way you want in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT car.*, GROUP_CONCAT(color SEPARATOR ',')
FROM car
INNER JOIN carColor ON car.id=carColor.carID
GROUP BY carColor.carID;
```

[[sqlfiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63632/1)

Be aware of the [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) option that can truncate your concat results.